# PHP switch statement doesn't recognize submit button

Tags: php, post, submit-button

I have a page that gets information from the database and should Update the information when submitted. I use "switch" statement but it doesn't recognize submit button value. Form codes are in the "personal_change_form.inc" file. Codes are as following. Thank you in advance for any kind of help.
personal_change.php

```
<?php
/* Name:    personal_change.php
 * Desc:    This page updates information if there is a change
 */
 include("misc.inc");

 session_start();
 if(@$_SESSION['auth']  != "yes")
    {
        header("Location:user_login.php");
        exit();
    }

     switch ( $_POST['button'])
{
    case "Update":

$connect    =   mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$database)
                or die("Couldn't connect to database.");
 $sql   =   "SELECT * FROM data WHERE loginName='{$_SESSION['logname']}'";
 $result =  mysqli_query($connect,$sql)
        or die ("Couldn't execute query.");
 $row=  mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
 extract($row);
if($value != $_POST['value'])
    {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO data (loginName,createDate,password,                                                                    firstName,lastName,title,gender,course,sector,experience,qualific,location,mobile,email) VALUES                                     ('$_POST[loginName]',
                    '',
                    SHA1('$_POST[password]'),
                    '$_POST[firstName]',
                    '$_POST[lastName]',
                    '$_POST[Title]',
                    '$_POST[Gender]',
                    '$_POST[course]',
                    '$_POST[Sector]',
                    '$_POST[experience]',
                    '$_POST[qualific]',
                    '$_POST[Location]',
                    '$_POST[mobile]',
                    '$_POST[email]')";


                    mysqli_query($connect,$sql)
    or die("Couldn't execute query");
    header("location:personal.php");


    }

    break;
    default:
    include("personal_change_form.inc");
}


 ?>
```

personal_change_form.inc

```
<?php
/*  Program:    personal_change_form.inc
 *  Desc:       This program displays information from the database 
 *              and allow user to change it.
 */
 include("misc.inc");
$personal_change_array  =   array ("loginName"  =>  "User Name:",
                    "password"  =>  "Password:",
                    "firstName" =>  "First Name:",
                    "lastName"  =>  "Last Name:",
                    "title"     =>  "Title:",
                    "gender"    =>  "Gender:",
                    "course"    =>  "Courses offered:",
                    "sector"    =>  "Industry sector:",
                    "experience"=>  "Trainer experience(years):",
                    "qualific"  =>  "Academic qualifications:",
                    "location"  =>  "Location\City:",
                    "mobile"    =>  "Mobile:",
                    "email"     =>  "E-mail:");
?>
<html>
<head><title>Update Information</title></head>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
    label {font-weight:bold; float:left; width:27%;
    margin-right: .5em; text-align:right;}
            fieldset {border:2px solid #000000 }
    legend {font-weight:bold; font-size: 1.2em;
            margin-bottom: 20px; text-align:center; padding-left:20px; padding-right:20px;border: 1px solid #888;
  border-right: 1px solid #666;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #666;
  padding: 5px;
   background-color: rgba(255,102,0,1.00)}
    h3  {text-align: center; margin: 2em;}
                #wrapper {margin:0; padding: 0;}
                #login  {position: absolute; left:0; width:40%;
                        padding: 1em 0; }
                #reg {position:absolute; left:40%; width:60%;
                        padding: 1em 0;}
                #field {padding-bottom: .5em}
                .menu   {margin-left:150px; padding-bottom: .5em; width:204px}
                .errors {font-weight: bold; font-size:12px font-style:italic;
                        font-size:90%; color: red; margin-top:0; text-align:center}
    -->
    </style>
<body>
        <form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>"
        method="POST">
        <fieldset><legend>UPDATE INFORMATION</legend>

<?php


echo    "<table  style='width:20%; left:25%; position:absolute; font-weight:bold' cellspacing='28.5'>\n";
     foreach($personal_change_array as $field=>$value)
 {
      echo "<tr><td>$value</td></tr>";
 }
 echo   "</table>";
 echo   "<table  style='width:10%; left:25%; position:relative; font-weight:bold' cellspacing='15'>\n";
 $connect   =   mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$database)
                or die("Couldn't connect to database.");
 $sql   =   "SELECT * FROM data WHERE loginName='{$_SESSION['logname']}'";
 $result =  mysqli_query($connect,$sql)
        or die ("Couldn't execute query.");
 $row=  mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
foreach($row as $field => $value)
{
    if($field!="createDate")
    {
        if($field=="password")
        {
            $type='password';
        }
            else
            {
                $type='text';
            }

echo "<tr><td><input ' type='$type' value=$value></input></td></tr>";

    }
}
echo "</table>";
?>

    <input type="submit" name="button"
         style='margin-left:40%; margin-bottom:.5em; margin-top:30px' value="Update" />

</fieldset></form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have tried your code, but even the button is not working (not clickable, not sending the form). Maybe because some other mistakes? For example the line in personal_change_form.inc `echo "<tr><td><input ' type='$type' value=$value></input></td></tr>";` there is a surplus ' sign, but there is no name for the fields...
Otherwise you do can check the value of submit button, it should work.

Comment: `sha1` is not a secure hash. Use [`password_hash`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) to hash passwords.

Comment: @GezaBoehm the line you mentioned is not button, it is form input fields. Button line is as following: <input type="submit" name="button"
         style='margin-left:40%; margin-bottom:.5em; margin-top:30px' value="Update" />

Comment: Understood, i know which line is the button :-)
I have mentioned maybe other errors cause your script to not work. Because normally the method you use is good (sending button value and check with switch), i have double checked it on my server.

Answer (score 0):

The button names are not submit, so the php $_POST['submit'] value is not set. As in isset($_POST['submit']) evaluates to false.

you can use javascript function instead to post the form by giving id to buttons and there you can get button value by id and the serialize the form and submit to your desired action.

for example you can use

```
<form id="my_awesome_form" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>"
        method="POST">
</form>
    <input id="submit_button" type="submit" name="button"
         style='margin-left:40%; margin-bottom:.5em; margin-top:30px' value="Update" />
    <script>
        var buttonVal = $('#submit_button').val();

        var form = $('#my_awesome_form').serialize();
    form.push({button: buttonVal});
      form.find('select:first').change( function() {
        $.ajax( {
          type: "POST",
          url: form.attr( 'action' ),
          data: form.serialize(),
          success: function( response ) {
            console.log( response );
          }
        } );
      } );
</script>
```

now use ajax call to submit form and send buttonVal with data to ajax call

Comment: Thank you for your effort but I am bad at javascript. In my code button name is 'button' so I have used $_POST['button']

Comment: @vicky92727 i have tried the button posting, it works well. The name/value pair is arriving in the $_POST superglobal. On which system/server have you experienced problems with it?

Comment: @GezaBoehm I was wrong button value can be get by name and id , my jquery solution was for NahidMirzayer as Nahid was facing problem in getting these values so I suggested to try jquery.